# Create custom system table value type SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a global stored procedure in the `master` database in SQL Server 2008 using undocumented stored procedure:

```
exec sp_MS_marksystemobject 'MyProcedureName'
```

That procedure uses a custom table type.

Is it possible to make a custom table type like system type, global to server? I want to use something similar as if I use `int`, `varchar` or `date` types.

Sorry for my English. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried the example at the bottom of this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007(v=sql.105).aspx (CREATE TYPE). What issues do you encounter?

Comment: I can create the table type, but I need to be global in the server, similar to the system types (int, varchar, float, double, date, etc ...). When i define the data type is only visible in the database that created it.

Comment: And sp_MS_marksystemobject  doesn't work on it? If not you might have to try creating a synonym in each database.

Comment: I will try it, but my objective is create a new custom system type, not a global store procedure, i can create the procedure, but your parameters not (custom table type).

Comment: I don't see anything saying `sp_MS_marksystemobject` is just for stored procedures. I'm interested to see if it works for types as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that any user-defined table type is bound to the sys schema in the sysobjects (and sys.objects) table, while bound to the dbo schema in the sys.table_types table. The TL;DR is that [OBJECT_ID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) will return null for user-defined table types. OBJECT_ID() is called within sp_ms_marksystemobject.

```
USE master;

GO

CREATE TYPE
    dbo.tt_test
AS TABLE
    (
        test_col int
    );

GO

SELECT
    so_name = so.name,
    so_schema_id = so.uid,
    so_schema_name = s1.name,
    tt_name = tt.name,
    tt_schema_id = tt.schema_id,
    tt_schema_name = s2.name,
    mod_name = 'TT_' + tt.name + '_' + convert(nvarchar(8), convert(varbinary(8), tt.type_table_object_id, 2), 2)
FROM
    sys.sysobjects so
    inner join
    sys.table_types tt
        on so.id = type_table_object_id
    inner join
    sys.schemas s1
        on so.uid = s1.schema_id
    inner join
    sys.schemas s2
        on tt.schema_id = s2.schema_id
WHERE
    tt.name = 'tt_test';

+---------------------+--------------+----------------+---------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+
|       so_name       | so_schema_id | so_schema_name | tt_name | tt_schema_id | tt_schema_name |      mod_name       |
+---------------------+--------------+----------------+---------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+
| TT_tt_test_2B4A5C8F |            4 | sys            | tt_test |            1 | dbo            | TT_tt_test_2B4A5C8F |
+---------------------+--------------+----------------+---------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Inner workings of sp_ms_marksystemobject below, but the relevant line is here:

```
select @objid = object_id(@objname, 'local')
```

Attempted replication using:

```
SELECT tt_object_id = object_id('tt_test', 'local');
```

Returns:

```
+--------------+
| tt_object_id |
+--------------+
| NULL         |
+--------------+
```

Attempted replication using:

```
SELECT so_object_id = object_id('TT_tt_test_2B4A5C8F', 'local');
```

Returns:

```
+--------------+
| so_object_id |
+--------------+
| NULL         |
+--------------+
```

Code for sp_ms_marksystemobject:

```
exec sp_helptext 'sp_ms_marksystemobject'

---------------------------- sp_MS_marksystemobject -----------------------------
-- FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY ... DO NOT DOCUMENT --
-- This procedure sets a bit in sysobjects.  This bit has no meaning, various
--    groups (starfigther, davinci, replication) use it for different things
-- MSQL makes no warranty, express or implied, on what objects will or will
--    not have this bit set.  Use at your own risk.
--   
create procedure sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject
    @objname    nvarchar(517),  -- 517 is max for two part name
    @namespace    varchar(10) = NULL        -- database, server or null
as

    set nocount on
    declare @objid    int
    declare @owner    sysname,
            @ns        int,            -- namespace enumeration value
            @object    sysname

    -- ============================================================
    -- DEVNOTE:
    --    x_eonc_TrgOnServer        = 20,    // Namespace for Triggers on the Server
    --    x_eonc_TrgOnDatabase    = 21,    // Namespace for Triggers on Databases
    --  x_eonc_Standard            = 0        // Standard Namespace
    -- ============================================================

    if not (@namespace is NULL)
    begin
    select @ns = (case lower(@namespace)
                when 'server' then 20
                when 'database' then 21
                end)
    end
    else
    begin
        set @ns = 0 -- null means standard namespace
    end

    -- bail out on invalid namespace.
    if @ns is null
        begin
        raiserror('sp_MS_marksystemobject: Invalid NameSpace ''%ls''',0,1,@namespace)
        return (1)
    end

    -- CHECK THE OBJECT NAME --
    select @object = parsename(@objname, 1),
            @owner = parsename(@objname, 2)

    -- ============================================================
    -- DEVNOTE:
    --    x_eonc_TrgOnServer        = 20,    // Namespace for Triggers on the Server
    --    x_eonc_TrgOnDatabase        = 21,    // Namespace for Triggers on Databases
    -- ============================================================

    if @ns = 20 or @ns = 21
    begin
        if NOT (@owner is null)
        begin
            -- schema name specified for extended trigger. Error out
            raiserror(1094,-1,-1)
            return (1)
        end
    end

    -- use master db for server level trigger
    if @ns = 20
    begin
        select @objid = object_id from sys.server_triggers where name = @objname
    end
    else if @ns = 21
    begin
        select @objid = object_id from sys.triggers where name = @objname and parent_class = 0
    end
    else
    begin
        select @objid = object_id(@objname, 'local')
    end


    -- CHECK THE OBJECT OWNER (MUST BE DBO) --
    -- DO THE UPDATE --
    BEGIN TRAN
    if not (@objid is null)
    begin
        if @ns = 0
        begin
            EXEC %%Object(MultiName = @objname).LockMatchID(ID = @objid, Exclusive = 1, BindInternal = 0)
            if @@error <> 0
                select @objid = null
            else
            begin
                if @owner is null
                    select @owner = N'dbo'

                EXEC %%Object( Owner = @owner, Name = @object ).SetSystem()

            end
        end
        else
        begin
            EXEC %%TriggerEx(MultiName = @objname).ValidateAndSetSystem(
                                                    ID = @objid, NameSpaceClass = @ns)
        end
    end

    if @objid is null
    begin
        raiserror('sp_MS_marksystemobject: Invalid object name ''%ls''',0,1,@objname)
        COMMIT TRAN
        return (1)
    end

    COMMIT TRAN
    return (0)    -- sp_MS_marksystemobject
```